# Super User - Suggest adding an operating system tag

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, tags

When asking a question on Super User, add a suggestion for users to include their "operating system" when adding tags.

It's such a *common omission* in questions on Super User, I think an extra reminder would be justified.

Answer (score 5):

I think it would be nice if the posting guidelines for questions gave some more definitive tag suggestions. Like what you said, if you have a problem, don't forget to include your OS (if you think it is important).

Answer (score 5):

I made the default tag suggestion help text "osx linux windows"

Answer (score 2):

I agree. Although I wouldn't get too sophisticated with this. Maybe just a little note on the page near the tags list.

Comment: Right, I wouldn't want the user to feel like they **have** to include an os specific tag on every question. Otherwise you have a lot of useless tags getting spammed around.

Comment: That's all I am suggesting. An extra bit of text by the tags box. "Include your OS."

Comment: @rcartaino: I would like it to be a bit more clear than that. We don't want people adding in "windows-xp" to a tag that is asking about how to use Gmail.

Comment: How do I add a signature in gmail using Windows XP and a Netgear wireless router?

Comment: @TheTXI - "Include your OS, if relevant." Trying to keep it simple/brief. Tag editors can help out here, if there are *unnecessary* tags.

Comment: @Jon B, you'll need to drop that current thinking and use jQuery instead. – random 0 s

Comment: Ólafur Waage 2 mins ago – Ólafur Waage 5 mins ago – Ólafur Waage 3 mins ago

Comment: I've noticed the answer to a lot of questions is 7-Zip or VLC. If we'd add a note to try those 2 apps, it would remove the number of questions by half :)

Comment: Maybe there's 7-zip and VLC flash mobs?

Comment: 7-Zip or VLC? Try jQuery instead!

Answer (score 2):

Sometimes you can infer stuff from *missing* tags. When the OS is not included, it is safe to assume that we are talking about Windows.

Comment: Sometimes. But *inferred* tags don't allow people to use the tag system effectively; searching by tag, interesting/ignored tags, etc.

Answer (score 1):

the site is about trusting users as well, if we start "suggesting" to include the operating system tag, later people will want to include a hardware specific tag, and later start **demanding** stuff.

IMHO, if you believe a operating system is relevant to the questions, would be enough to add a comment **politely** asking the user to add one, or someone with enough rep. This kind of participation is what make users learn and improve their questions.