# Having to ask for the user's OS...

Tags: discussion, asking-questions

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Super User - Suggest adding an operating system tag](https://meta.superuser.com/questions/592/super-user-suggest-adding-an-operating-system-tag)

We frequently have to ask about the OS the user runs, [the Ask Question page](https://superuser.com/questions/ask) doesn't ask to include it.

Would it be a good idea to include a sentence in the right side that suggest the user to specify his OS?

Comment: @random: Oops, didn't show up as a suggestion because I typed OS, thanks. :-)

Comment: the rules for this have changed a bit.. we now show 3 random top 20 tags in the help area, so it will vary per build but should be top 20 no matter what

Comment: @JeffAtwood: Thanks, cool to see you active here. 8 tags of them are an OS so it would always show one, I doubt it if people read them though...

Comment: @TomWij Jeff actually has been active for a while here :P

Comment: @BloodPhilia: Yeah, but his quick response was remarkable. :)

Comment: @TomWij haha, as is yours! Only took you a minute to respond to mine!